# Create generic delegate for class

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

Let's say I have very simple class:

```
class Box<T> {
  var boxedObject:T

  init(object: T) {
    self.boxedObject = object
  }
}
```

What I would like to achieve now is to add delegate, which can inform me that value in box has changed:

```
protocol BoxDelegate<T>: class {
    func valueInBoxChanged(box: Box<T>) -> Void
}

class Box<T> {
    var boxedObject: T {
        didSet {
            self.delegate?.valueInBoxChanged(self)
        }
    }
    weak var delegate: BoxDelegate<T>?

    init(object: T) {
        self.boxedObject = object
    }
}
```

This code is of course not working, because we don't have generic delegates. I can make delegate to be a struct with closure, but it's a bit ugly solution. How I should do such things in Swift?

Comment: In this specific case, where the delegate only implements one method, I'd suggest simply moving the generic type declaration to the method itself. Of course this would be inelegant if the protocol declares multiple methods, but in this simple case it's pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Let say that instead of `BoxDelegate` you have a class, and let's call it `Listener` :

```
public typealias ValueChanged <T> = (T) -> Void
public class Listener<T> {
    var valueChanged: ValueChanged<T>

    public init(_ valueChanged: @escaping ValueChanged<T>) {
        self.valueChanged = valueChanged
    }
}
```

`Box` can now be written like that:

```
class Box<T> {
    // the listener needs to be weak in order to be deallocated when the that is
    // observing the changes is deallocated
    weak private(set) var listener: Listener<T>?
    init(_ listener: Listener<T>) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
}
```

and you can now have a wrapper class for the properties whose state you need to observe:

```
class Observed<T> {
    var listeners: [Box<T>] = []
    private let queue: DispatchQueue = .main
    var value: T {
        didSet {
            notifyListeners()
        }
    }
    func notifyListeners() {
        notifyListeners(value)
    }
    
    func notifyListeners(_ value: T) {
        queue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.listeners.forEach { (box) in
                box.listener?.valueChanged(value)
            }
        }
    }
    func bind(_ listener: Listener<T>) {
        listeners.append(Box(listener))
    }
    
    func bind(_ listener: @escaping ValueChanged<T>) -> Listener<T> {
        let listener = Listener(listener)
        listeners.append(Box(listener))
        return listener
    }
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

and even have a property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Bind<T> {
    let observable: Observed<T>
    init(wrappedValue: T) {
        observable = Observed(wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            observable.value
        }
        set {
            observable.value = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var projectedValue: Observed<T> {
        observable
    }
}
```

usage :

```
var text = ""
class ViewModel {
    @Bind
    var isOn: Bool = false
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()

let bond = viewModel.$isOn.bind { isOn in
    if isOn {
        text = "on"
    } else {
        text = "off"
    }
    
}
viewModel.isOn = true
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date().advanced(by: 0.1))
text
viewModel.isOn = false
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date().advanced(by: 0.1))
text
```

[image: In a playground]

Answer (score 0):

Due to type constrained Protocol with Swift, you might not be able to do what you were trying to do above.  What you could do is create a closure when delegate is set and call the closure later.

Here is what would make your case simpler to some extent,

```
protocol BoxDelegate: class {
    associatedtype T
    func valueInBoxChanged(box: Box<T>) -> Void
}

class Box<T> {

    var notifyClosure: (Void -> Void)?

    var boxedObject: T {
        didSet {
            self.notifyClosure?()
        }
    }

    func setBoxDelegate<M where M:BoxDelegate, M.T == T>(delegate: M) {
        notifyClosure = {
            delegate.valueInBoxChanged(self)
        }
    }

    init(object: T) {
        self.boxedObject = object
    }
}
```

So, you dont need to add extra struct with a closure to have it working. Instead you would not create a property for BoxDelegate, but create a method to set it and create a closure object based on that.