# Weak reference implementing a (generic) protocol

Tags: swift, generics, delegates, protocols

I want to create an array of weak references implementing a protocol for observable functionality.
If possible this protocol should have an associated type, so I would not need to create identical ones for each type.

However in Swift 4 this does not seem to work, what I want is basically this:

```
protocol DelegateBase: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Item
    func onDataUpdated(data: [Item])
}

protocol Delegate : DelegateBase where Item == Int {
    // Will have func onDataUpdated(data: [Int])
}

// T should be a class implementing Delegate, but cannot find a way to 
// define T in a way that the Swift compiler accepts it
class WeakListener<T> {
    weak var listener : T?

    init(listener: T) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
}

class Implementation {
    val listeners = [WeakListener<Delegate>]()
}
```

If I define everything as non-generic I can make it work, but I would like the convenience of not having to copy paste a concrete version of DelegateBase for each type I want to support.

```
// This works but is clunky

protocol DelegateA {
    func onDataUpdated(data: [Int])
}
// DelegateB with type Double, DelegateC with type X

class WeakListenerA {
    weak var listener : DelegateA?

    init(listener: DelegateA) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
}
// WeakListenerB with type Double, WeakListenerC with type X

class ImplementationA {
    val listeners = [WeakListenerA]()
}
// ImplementationB with type Double, ImplementationC with type X
```

**EDIT: Intended usage**

Basically I want to implement remote-backed repository where UIViewControllers can listen in on events happening inside the repository even though they aren't actively requesting data.

I want the listener to be generic, so I don't need to clone everything for each type. I want weak references since then no manual work is needed for managing them apart from adding listeners.

```
protocol DelegateBase: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Item
    func onDataModified(data: [Item])
    func onDataRefreshed(data: [Item])
}

protocol IntDelegate : DelegateBase where Item == Int {
    // Will have
    //func onDataModified(data: [Int])
    //func onDataRefreshed(data: [Int])
}

// Listener should implement the delegate T, that extends DelegateBase 
// with a type
class WeakListener<T : DelegateBase> {
    weak var listener : T?

    init(listener: T) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
}

class IntRepository {
    var listeners = [WeakListener<IntDelegate>]()
    var data = [Int]()

    func addListener(_ listener: IntDelegate /* UIViewController implementing IntDelegate*/) {
        listeners.add(listener)
    }

    func add() {
        // data is updated, notify weak listeners
        data.append(1)
        for listener in listeners {
            listener.listener?.onDataModified(data: data)
        }
    }

    func refresh() {
        // data refreshed from a remote source
        for listener in listeners {
            listener.listener?.onDataRefreshed(data: data)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func cleanupListeners() {
        self.listeners = self.listeners.filter({$0.listener != nil})
    }

  // Singleton for example
    fileprivate static var _instance: IntImplementation!
    public class func shared() -> IntImplementation {
        if _instance == nil {
            _instance = IntImplementation()
        }

        return _instance!
    }
}

class IntViewController: UIViewController, IntDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        IntImplementation.shared().addListener(self)
    }

    func onDataModified(data: [Int]) {
        // update UI
    }

    func onDataRefreshed(data: [Int]) {
        // update UI
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with it ? And what is the expected result ? this remind me of this [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67327655/1425697) I've made on a similar post

Comment: Instead of single observable values I wanted to have a delegate which would communicate changes in a repository.

Comment: Could you add a _usage section_ in your question ? To show how you want to use your delegate.

Comment: I added a usage section, thanks for taking the time to try and help me

Comment: ok my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67327655/1425697) uses closures, and you use protocols but it's the same principle: your `IntRepository` looks a lot like my `Observed`, your `WeakListener` looks like my `Box` etc. @NewDev's answer uses protocol and it looks like it also does what you want

Answer (score 0):

Because the `DelegateBase` (and by extension, the `Delegate`) protocol has an associated type (unlike `DelegateA`), you cannot use it as a type; you can only use some concrete type that conforms to it.

For what you're trying to do, you don't actually need the `Delegate` protocol. You seem to want a `WeakListener` generic with respect to `Item` type, which you can declare like so:

```
class WeakListener<T: DelegateBase> {
    weak var listener : T?

    init(listener: T) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
}
```

In other words, the above works with some concrete `T` type that conforms to `DelegateBase`.

Let's say you had such a concrete type for `Int`:

```
class ConcreteIntDelegateA: DelegateBase {
    func onDataUpdated(data: [Int]) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you could create a `WeakListener` for `ConcreteIntDelegateA` because it conforms to `DelegateBase` and further specifies that an `Item` is `Int`

```
let listener: WeakListener<ConcreteIntDelegateA>
```

So, it works for a concrete type, but you cannot do this for a protocol `DelegateBase`, because `DelegateBase` doesn't conform to `DelegateBase` (protocols don't conform to protocols, including themselves):

```
let listener: WeakListener<DelegateBase> // ERROR
```

---

This gives you the ability to create array of listeneres for a specific concrete type, e.g. `[WeakListener<ConcreteIntDelegateA>]` or `[WeakListener<ConcreteIntDelegateB>]`, but not mixed, because these types are unrelated even though both `ConcreteDelegateX` conform to `DelegateBase`.

To get around it is to create a type-erased type, e.g. `class AnyDelegate<Item>: DelegateBase`, which takes a concrete type in its `init`:

```
class AnyDelegate<Item>: DelegateBase {
    private let onDataUpdated: ([Item]) -> Void

    init<C: DelegateBase>(_ c: C) where C.Item == Item {
        self.sonDataUpdated = c.onDataUpdated(data:)
    }

    func onDataUpdated(data: [Item]) {
        onDataUpdated(data)
    }
}
```

```
let anyIntA = AnyDelegate(ConcreteIntDelegateA())
let anyIntB = AnyDelegate(ConcreteIntDelegateB())
let anyIntListeners: [WeakListener<AnyDelegate<Int>>] = [anyIntA, anyIntB]
```

Comment: Although this works, defining separate concrete classes does not work for what I'm trying to do. What I wanted to do was implement an observer system where a list of weak references implementing a delegate could be used to communicate changes in the inside the observable, with generic typing for what the delegate reports.

Comment: @MarkusM. You need to specify clearly what you're trying to do, ideally in code (even if it doesn't compile) and how you intend to use it. Bear in mind, that if you have a protocol with an associated type, you can no longer use it in place of a concrete type.

Comment: I added a usage section, hope my intention is more clear. Thanks for taking the time to try and help me.

Comment: @MarkusM., ok, so, in your usage example, `IntViewController` is the same as `ConcreteIntDelegateA` here. Because you can't have a type `IntDelegate` or `WeakListener<IntDelegate>`, you need to create a type-erased type like `AnyDelegate<Item>`, exactly like I showed in the last part of my answer. Then, you could have `[WeakListener<AnyDelegate<Int>>]`, and you'd add your concrete types as `.shared.addListener(AnyDelegate(self))`

Comment: What would the extension look like for the class implemeting ConcreteIntDelegateA?

Comment: @MarkusM., Not sure what you mean by "extension", but in my example `ConcreteIntDelegateA` is a concrete class conforming to `DelegateBase` - basically what you have as a `IntViewController`...

Comment: It compiles but the weak references are cleaned up as soon as they are added to the list. It seems this might not be possible as I wanted. I think i'll just create a custom delegate for each repository type.

Comment: @MarkusM., ah I see.. Nothing is holding a reference to the `AnyDelegate` instance, and so it's immediately deinitialized. Yeah, more care is needed here to keep a strong reference to these instances

Comment: @MarkusM., here's another answer that deals with a similar issue that might help  (I haven't tried it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724857/can-we-create-type-erasing-weak-references-with-non-optional-properties-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was just throwing away the `DelegateBase`. To provide some type conformance I created a generic base repository and enforce the delegate type during runtime when adding listeners

```
import UIKit

protocol IntDelegate : AnyObject {
    func onDataModified(data: [Int])
    func onDataRefreshed(data: [Int])
}

class WeakListener {
    weak var listener : AnyObject?

    init(listener: AnyObject) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
}


class RepositoryBase<T> {
    private var _listeners = [WeakListener]()
    var listeners: [T] {
        get {
            // Remove dead listeners
            self._listeners = self._listeners.filter({($0.listener as? T) != nil})
            return self._listeners.map({ $0.listener as! T })
        }
    }

    func addListener(_ listener: AnyObject) {
        assert(listener is T)
        _listeners.append(WeakListener(listener: listener))
    }
}

class IntRepository : RepositoryBase<IntDelegate> {
    var data = [Int]()

    func add() {
        // data is updated, notify weak listeners
        data.append(1)
        for listener in self.listeners {
            listener.onDataModified(data: data)
        }
    }

    func refresh() {
        // data refreshed from a remote source
        for listener in self.listeners {
            listener.onDataRefreshed(data: data)
        }
    }

  // Singleton for example
    fileprivate static var _instance: IntRepository!
    public class func shared() -> IntRepository {
        if _instance == nil {
            _instance = IntRepository()
        }

        return _instance!
    }
}

class IntViewController: IntDelegate {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        IntRepository.shared().addListener(self)
        IntRepository.shared().add()
    }

    func onDataModified(data: [Int]) {
        print("modified")
    }

    func onDataRefreshed(data: [Int]) {
        print("refreshed")
    }
}

IntViewController().viewDidLoad() // Prints "modified"
```