# Swift closure keeps retaining weakly captured object

Tags: ios, swift

I use VIP cycle architecture in my project, where `UIViewController` has strong reference to `Interator`, `Interactor` has strong reference to `Presenter` and `Presenter` has weak reference to `UIViewController`:

UIViewController **->** Interactor **->** Presenter - -> UIViewController

After UIViewController dismiss all other module components usually deallocate too.
I have an `someSharedService` that fetches data from server in background queue and send updates in the queue via 'reactive' `someSharedProperty`.
Interactor is subscribed to the property:

```
someSharedService.someSharedProperty.subscribeForUpdate { [weak self] _ in
    self?.presenter.sendUpdates()
}
```

And presenter updates view:

```
func sendUpdates() {
    // this string crashes the app
    view!.render()
}
```

I know that crash is happening because `view` is force unwrapped, but the root of the problem is that after `viewController` is dismissed `interactor` is still alive. But it must be deallocated right after the view deallocated. After checking out memory graph I found out that it's a closure (and only it) holding the `interactor`, despite it captured weakly.

Here's my implementation of the reactive property:

```
protocol Subscribable {

    associatedtype SubscribeType

    typealias UpdateResultsHandler = (_ values: SubscribeType) -> Void

    var subscribers: [UpdateResultsHandler?] { get }

    func subscribeForUpdate(_ updateHandler: @escaping UpdateResultsHandler)
}

class SubscribableProperty<Type>: Subscribable {

    typealias SubscribeType = Type

    private(set) var subscribers: [UpdateResultsHandler?] = []

    var value: Type {
        didSet {
            subscribers.forEach {
                $0?(value)
            }
        }
    }

    init(value: Type) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func subscribeForUpdate(_ updateHandler: @escaping UpdateResultsHandler) {
        subscribers.append(updateHandler)
    }
}
```

That's how it looks in memory graph after crash:
[image: Memory graph]

Comment: So `UpdateResultsHandler` is a closure? When you call it, how do you do it? I'd say you should be doing something like `subscribableProperty.subscribeForUpdate { [weak self] _ in ... }`? So the closure doesn't retain `self` strongly?

Comment: I've updated the post with `Subscribable` protocol. 
Yes, `UpdateResultsHandler` is a closure. It's added in `subscribers` array when object subscribers for update via `subscribeForUpdate` method. And when property value updates (didSet) it calls each subscriber closure if it's not `nil`

Comment: Are you sure `sendUpdates` is running on main thread? It accesses view, and even if view is not deallocated, that will crash on any thread except for main

Comment: Also your `subscribers: [UpdateResultsHandler?]` is a strong reference even though it's optional. You probably need to weakify items in this array, for example use `WeakListener` idea from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67717322/5318223

Comment: @KirilS. `sendUpdates` is not running on main thread, but `render` method inside `view` is.

I will try the weakifying array items, thanks for the suggestion.
But I wonder why I should weakify them if the closure has already captured interactor weakly, so there must be no retain cycle (and memory graph doesn't show anything retaining closure (displayed as malloc), only closure retaining interactor.

Comment: Your code seems retain-cycle free. Are you sure that the subscribeForUpdate closure is holding a strong reference to the interactor? Is there any other closure or method that you call from the interactor that might lead to capturing a strong reference? (Some API might not make it obvious they they capture a reference, for example if a argument is @autoclosure)

Comment: @ChristosKoninis I've added a screenshot of memory graph. And I analyzed it one more time and now I have doubts that it's the closure retaining the Interactor. An object that's holding it is just a Malloc. If I tap to this Malloc and go QuickHelp tab I see this: `weak var \`self\`: ViewController?`.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis so my next suggestion is that `UIVIewController` somehow stays in memory as a nameless `Malloc` (not sure if I understand the mechanism correctly), retaining the `Interactor`. And maybe it also connected with the `service` sending updates on background thread while `uiviewcontroller` deallocation handling on main thread. And also the `uiviewcontroller` is an embeded in another vc so maybe it takes more time to go from memory for it after it's parent `viewcontroller` dismiss.

Comment: @AlexSh. Unfortunately the memory graph screenshot you attached does not contain any information, I think you need to zoom/expand it to display the nodes between the malloc and the interactor so that you can find the object that holds the reference. Also are you sure that the viewController is deallocated, did you confirm this by check that the deinint is called?

Comment: @ChristosKoninis, I confirmed by filtering memory graph and not founding it. There are Interactor and Presenter presented in it and no sign of ViewController. 
There are no other nodes between the malloc and the interactor, it's only showing stack of calls.